# Using MediaInfo Software to determine Container and Codec associated with video?

Tags: video, containers, mp4, codec, windows-media-player

My understanding of the technical aspects associated with Video files is very basic. 
We have a Media File that failed to play on a regular Microsoft Windows Media Player.
We wanted to determine the Container and Codec that the Video file expected.
We used MediaInfo Software to gather technical information about the Video File

Please tell me what Container and Codec that the Video File expects based on the following technical data shown by the MediaInfo Software analysis:

```
General
Unique ID                                : 199699655166945097281031563218776713670 (0x963CC12BF5060B3082021A86238B69C6)
Complete name                            : D:\temp3\2014-03-28+Stanford+v+Pepperdine+3-0.mp4
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4 / Version 2
File size                                : 230 MiB
Duration                                 : 2h 5mn
Overall bit rate                         : 257 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2014-03-29 05:14:28
Writing application                      : mkvmerge v6.6.0 ('The Edge Of The In Between') built on Dec  1 2013 17:55:00
Writing library                          : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=32
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration                                 : 2h 5mn
Bit rate                                 : 252 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.009
Stream size                              : 226 MiB (98%)
Title                                    : Video
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- .MP4 file - this is expected to be a MPEG-4 Part 14 compliant container file, however MediaInfo detects it as Matroska file, and the correct extension would be .MKV
- MPEG-4 Part 10 also known as H.264 video stream in the file, video encoding/codec

I am putting this up from the comments:

> I would suggest that you re-encode (more specifically, re-multiplex or re-mux) the file into H.264 .MP4 file. The file would hold the same video and it should be playable by stock Windows 7. FFmpeg can handle the conversion.

- [How to simply convert video files (i.e.: MKV to MP4)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396883/how-to-simply-convert-video-files-i-e-mkv-to-mp4)
- [ffmpeg: Converting MKV to MP4 lossless](https://superuser.com/questions/758080/ffmpeg-converting-mkv-to-mp4-lossless)

Comment: If the video file is within MPEG-4 container and uses H.264 codec then why won't a standard Microsoft Windows Media Player play the file?  It's weird, we shouldn't have to install any codecs to make it work.  It should work on a standard Microsoft Windows Media Player that comes with Windows 7 or 8 without any separate codec install.  Why does it fail to play on my Windows Computer?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the section where MediaInfo detects the file as Matroska/MKV, please see updated answer above. And this explains WMP behavior - it does not offer support for MKV (it does offer MP4 support but only since Windows 7)

Comment: Is there a way to get the very specific file containing the proper MKV (Matroska) container specifications so that can we can some how install on a standard Windows 7 computer?

Comment: Note that this question is voted to be moved to SuperUser.com which is the proper site for it. I would suggest that you re-encode (more specifically, re-multiplex or re-mux) the file into H.264 .MP4 file. The file would hold the same video and it should be playable by stock Windows 7. FFmpeg can handle the conversion.